# Elastic beanstalk periodic tasks on autoscaled environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, periodic-task

On an autoscaled environment running a periodic task, if the environment is scaled up, do the periodic tasks get run on each instance? Or more specifically, does each instance then post to the queue leading to multiple "periodic tasks" running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If there's some periodic task that should only be triggered once, you should have a separate auto scale environment of minimum 1 maximum one instance to either perform the task or trigger it on one of your servers (maybe make a request to your load balancer and one of your instances will perform the task)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, behind the screen it's just a cron job on all your instances. The default scenario for using periodic tasks is to read the tasks from the SQS queue on the worker nodes.

So yes, if you doing some kind of posting what has to happen only once, then you either need to put some logic between or use a different solution.
(For example generating some kind of time based ID which identifies the cycle of the cron job. So messages from the same cycle are having the same id, easy to filter them/ ignore everything after the firs.